# Integrating Java Swing with GIT GUI

Tags: java, git, swing, integration, jgit

I have developed a Screen using Java Swing with couple of actions related to delivery/release activities. I have installed GIT GUI of version **2.5.1**. It would be feasible if the newly developed screen integrated with GIT GUI.
GIT GUI have been developed with **Tcl/Tk(Widget Toolkit)** of version **8.6.4**. Do we have any option to integrate the newly developed Swing screen with GIT GUI?

Comment: Why don't you just use JGit to perform Git related operations and make your Swing UI a Git UI